# Zend Translate Routing for custom modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-translate, zend-router

How do I have to set up the routing for a default language in Zend Framework on a custom module, in my case the admin module.

I have the following code:

```
$langRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
   ':lang/admin',
   array(
      'lang' => 'ro',
   )
);
```

what i wan't to obtain is url's like the following:

```
www.example.com/ro/admin/pages/add/62
www.example.com/ro/admin/pages/index/by/date_modified/order/asc
```

etc.

Comment: How to change the default `lang` at run time when click on other language option from web sit?.

Comment: @AshwinP I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: In your Zend Controller Router you have added default lang ( language ) is set to 'ro' so, How can use change language from ro to like en, nl or hi etc...

Comment: I have another plugin that init's after the Translation and gets the language of the user. But this is not my problem, the user locale is detected correctly. I only don't know how to set it up for modules. Links like www.example.com/ro and www.example.com route both to the ro version, like i wan't it, but this doesn't happen for modules.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this will working:**

```
protected function _initRoutes() {
    $langRoute = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance ()->getRouter ();
    $langRoute->removeDefaultRoutes ();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
       ':lang/:module/:controller/:action/*',
        array (
            'lang' => 'ro',
            'module' => 'admin',
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => 'index'
        )
    );
    $langRoute->addRoute ( 'langrouter', $route );
}
```

Comment: It kind of works but what it doesn't work is the default url for example: www.example.com/admin/pages/index should route to default "ro". Do you know what I should add?